# How to query for multiple keys in-memory cache in Java?

Tags: java, caching

I have some persistent data in the rdms and csv files (they are independent objects, but I wanted to mention it because they are in different mediums, 
 I can not go with what rdbms provides, actually I do not want to do a trip to database for the next hour in even the data gets old). I need to store the data in memory for performance benefits and **query** (only read, no other operation) the objects based on multiple columns of it, and refresh the data every hour.

In my case ,what is a good way to store and query in-memory objects other than implementing my own object store and querying methods?  For instance, can you provide an example/link to replace the sql query as

```
select * from employees where emplid like '%input%' or surname like  '%input%' or email like  '%input%';
```

Sorry for the dummy query but it explains what kind of queries are possible.

Comment: Perhaps an ORM like Spring or Hibernate, though not sure of their CSV support. Personally I like the control of direct jdbc/etc

Comment: There are plenty in-memory cache solutions: Apache ignite, hazelcast, Oracle coherence, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go find yourself a key store implementation with the features you want.  Use your Query string as the key and the result as the value.  https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine Has quite a few features including record timeouts (like an hour).

For my own work, I use a LRU key store (limited to X entries) containing objects with the timeout information and I manually decide if the record is stale or not before I use it.  LRU is basically a linked-list which moves "read" records to the head of the list and drops the tail when records are added beyond the maximum desired size.  This keeps the popular records in the store longer.